# How to solve/simplify for a symbolic variable with sageMath

Tags: solver, sage, simplify

So I want to solve/simplify (not sure the correct term to use here) for the symbolic variable 'a' in this equation:

```
a == -1 - ((f - af) / n)
```

with sagemath. I should be expecting and answer of :

```
a == (-f - n) / (n- f)
```

I was able to do this using https://mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html but wasn't sure if this was possible with sagemath. I've tried a few ways using solve and simplify but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in three steps.

First declare the symbolic variables in Sage's symbolic ring (SR):

```
sage: a, f, n = SR.var('a, f, n')
```

Then define the equation, writing multiplication `a * f` explicitly:

```
sage: equation = a == -1 - ((f - a*f) / n)
```

Solve the equation in terms of the variable `a`:

```
sage: solve(equation, a)
[a == (f + n)/(f - n)]
```